# How can I make this button in Jetpack Compose react to the Press event faster when used with Modifier.verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())?

Tags: android, user-interface, components, android-jetpack-compose, composable

I have defined this button in Jetpack compose which changes the Button's style(changes the button color) when pressed. However, when I call the composable from within composable functions that use `Modifier.verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())`, the button stops responding to Press events immediately after being pressed (I have to press longer). Is there something wrong with my implementation?

```
@Composable
fun MyButton(
    buttonContent: @Composable () -> Unit,
    onButtonClicked: () -> Unit = {},
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    var isPressed by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    var interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
    // change button state based on current interaction
    LaunchedEffect(interactionSource) {
        interactionSource.interactions.collect { interaction ->
            isPressed = when (interaction) {
                is PressInteraction.Press -> true
                else -> false
            }
        }
    }

    Button(
        onClick = onButtonClicked,
        modifier = modifier,
        interactionSource = interactionSource,
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp),
        colors =
        if (!isPressed) {
            ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
                backgroundColor = Color.White
            )
        } else {
            ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
                backgroundColor = Color.Red
            )
        }
    ) {
        buttonContent()
    }
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun DemoWithoutVerticalScroll() {
    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        MyButton(
            onButtonClicked = {},
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(top=200.dp),
            buttonContent = {
                Text(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                    text = "button",
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center
                )
            }
        )
    }
}
@Preview
@Composable
fun DemoWithVerticalScroll() {
    // make the screen scrollable
    Column(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
    ) {
        MyButton(
            onButtonClicked = {},
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(top=200.dp),
            buttonContent = {
                Text(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                    text = "button",
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center
                )
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Try running each preview and pressing each button for a fraction of a second (clicking it in other words) to closely examine the problem.